# One Page Nav Bootstrap ScrollSpy Bug fixed header

Tags: jquery, scroll, twitter-bootstrap-3

My Fixed Header (Height: 144px) is causing problems on scrolling with One Page Nav.
Click on the Menu Links to scroll except the Contact Us (it will redirect to another page with this link). Notice that the OnePageNav's behavior is weird. I already coded an offset of 144px so that the scroll will go exactly to where it must stop, but a weird reaction of the scroll causes it to go down like a magnet attracting it.

Webpage Link:  http://yourwallart.com.au

P.S. I'm a newbie developer

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please check your code

```
<body data-target="#scrollElement">
```

`<body>` tag must be immediately starts after the end of `</head>`, but in your code it seems it is somewhere after header.

may be this cause issues in scrollspy, try this change first

still issue appears, create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so that i can check and debug on my own